# Calculate cost of ML training job - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I ran an ML training job in AI Platform - GCP. The job was run in Asia-Pacific region with a custom VM type of n1-highmem-8. The consumed ML units of the job was 3.66.

So by that fact, I calculated the cost of the job using below formula given in [1](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/pricing#ml-units):

Consumed ML units * $0.54(for Asia Pacific) = 3.66 * 0.54 = $1.9764 USD

I want to know whether it was calculated correctly or not. If I have missed anything please let me know. Do I also need to take into account any other variable like Compute Engine?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. There is no additional cost.

Comment: Okay.Thanks @GuoqingXu